# Hacking frequency range in tuner

Tags: fm-radio

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 with FM Tuner application. It is rooted.

I also took a look at Spirit FM Unlocked.

My question is: provided that this is illegal in some countries and not in others, and that AFAIK aviation frequencies are amplitude-modulated (AM), is it possible to (first and foremost) listen to radio frequencies beyond the 87.5/108 MHz standard ranges? Then is it possible to listen to AM frequencies wit Spirit FM or any other radio app after hacking the range?

Obviously, I just would like to listen, and fortunately it's not possible to interfere with a simple Android device into these frequencies.

Comment: Interesting question - have a dig around the kernel and its related FM chipset driver, it may be possible to alter it... but then again, this could be opening up a can of worms here, grey area, legalities etc?

Comment: According to [Chipworks' teardown](http://www.chipworks.com/blog/recentteardowns/2012/06/01/inside-the-samsung-galaxy-siii/), the FM functionality is part of the Broadcom BCM4334 chip, which also handles the Wi-Fi and Bluetooth.  If you can find a datasheet or anything on that, it might tell you if what you're wanting is even within the hardware's capabilities.